# Serialize / Deserialize Object into XML with (XStream)

Tags: java, xml, gson, xstream

I'm getting this error when trying to "deserialize" an object:

```
Cannot construct MyClass as it does not have a no-args constructor.
```

Looking at the docs, it means that XStream is not running in `enhanced mode`?

However, in the same JVM and using the same class the `Google Gson` library can serialize and deserialize objects without problem:

```
MyClass c;
c = (MyClass) new Gson().fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

So why XStream can't do to XML what Gson can do for JSON? Is this easy to patch in the XStream code or is this a limitation that is not easy to get around with?

I need to be able to serialize / deserialize Objects even those that have no-args constructor using this XStream library.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621372/xstream-no-args-constructor-error

Answer (score 0):

XStream requires that your class have a constructor with no args.

Those constructors don't have to be public, but they need to exist.

Comment: Yah I know, however I want my library to be able to handle classes with no no-args, however it seems that the Security manager in the GAE SDK won't allow such (where Google Gson is allowed, where other don't have such privilege)